# VueJS app as subdomain throws 404 when a path is added

Tags: vue.js

I have a portfolio site `portfolio.com` and a subdomain which points to a VueJS frontend hosted on Netlify `vuejsapp.portfolio.com`

Users upload files to the app and it generates a download link URL, say `vuejsapp.portfolio.com/download/048677a`. When I navigate to the link within the VueJS app (by clicking a button to redirect after it's uploaded) it redirects to the Download component without issue. But if I copy and paste that link directly in my browser it throws a 404 error. Why is this?

I know it has to do with a Vue Router configuration but I can't seem to find much information about it or perhaps I'm looking in the wrong place. Could someone tell me what I'm missing or point me to some relevant documentation please?

My `router.js` file:

```
 Vue.use(Router);

    export default new Router({
      mode: "history",
      base: process.env.BASE_URL,
      routes: [
        {
          path: "/",
          name: "home",
          component: Home,
        },
        {
          path: "/about",
          name: "about",
          component: About
        },
        {
          path: "/download/:id",
          name: "download",
          component: Download,
          props: route => ({ id: route.params.id }),
        }
      ]
    });
```

Comment: Can you navigate to any other route by just typing it in the address bar manually? If so, you have to set up a fallback to your root route within Netlify. Guess that should be possible.

Comment: @Aer0 I also have an empty "About" page that I've omitted, but when I try to manually type that url (`vuejsapp.portfolio.com/about`) into the browser I get the same 404 error. It's as if it's trying to pick up the path from the `portfolio.com` and not the subdomain. Note, on a normal `localhost` dev environment it works fine if I type it in manually.

Comment: So you're saying you have an additional route set in your routes just for `about`?

Comment: Essentially yes. I've updated the question with the route. I just omitted it originally because it wasn't relevant and just linked to an empty component.

Comment: Have you seen: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html ? Some server configuration is required if you're using history mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the code/setup is running properly on your local environment and only breaking on Netlify its pretty clear that you're running into a wrong server configuration issue.

Your Netlify environment has to know that it should always route any requests to `/` and leave the routing to your Vue App. You can read more about how to resolve that in the [Netlify docs](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/#syntax-for-the-redirects-file).

Comment: Thank you! This answer led me to do some more Googling on Netlify's redirects and I found this article https://medium.com/js-dojo/go-beyond-static-with-vue-router-33fc23035a68 which helped me solve my problem by creating the `_redirects` file in my app's `public` folder and adding `/* /index.html 200`. After deploying to Netlify all works well now.